# Add __getitem__ to module

Tags: python

So it's quite a simple question. how do I add `__getitem__` to a Python module. I mostly just want it as an ease of use, however it's confusing why it wouldn't let me 'just set it'. Below is a simple example of `__getitem__` semi-working, however I wish for the `other['test']` to work.

Here's the full output:

```
hello
hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    print other['test']
TypeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

main.py

```
import other
print other.get('test')
print other.__getitem__('test')
print other['test']
```

other.py

```
test = 'hello'

def __getitem__(name):
    return globals()[name]

get = __getitem__
```

I've tried to set `__getitem__` using `globals()` aswell, `globals()['__getitem__'] = __getitem__`. It didn't work. And I tried to set it in `main.py`. So I'm confused as to why it's so adamant in not allowing me to use `other['test']`.

If it's impossible, then a short reason would be good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Special methods are [looked up on the *type*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup-for-new-style-classes), not on an instance. Python looks for `type(other).__getitem__()` and that isn't available. You'd have to add the `__getitem__` method to the `module` type; you can't in Python.

You'd have to replace the whole `module` instance in `sys.modules` with an instance of your own class to achieve what you want:

```
class MyModule(object):
    def __init__(self, namespace):
        self.__dict__.update(namespace)
    def __getitem__(name):
        return self.__dict__[name]

import other
import sys
sys.modules[other.__name__] = MyModule(other.__dict__)
```

Answer (score 4):

This limitation doesn't just apply for modules, it applies for anything such that the type is not `object` or some subclass of `object`, or something with a metaclass that never bottoms out with `object` in the `mro`.

For example, you can also see this happening with type `type`:

```
In [32]: class Foo(type):
   ....:     pass
   ....: 

In [33]: type(Foo)
Out[33]: type

In [34]: Foo.__getitem__ = lambda x, y: x.__dict__.get(y)

In [35]: Foo.foo = "hello"

In [36]: Foo['foo']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-e354ca231ddc> in <module>()
----> 1 Foo['foo']

TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

In [37]: Foo.__dict__.get('foo')
Out[37]: 'hello'
```

The reason is that at the C-API level, both [`module`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/module.html) and [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/type.html#c.PyType_Type) are particular instances of [`PyTypeObject`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html) which don't implement the required protocol for inducing the same search mechanism that the `PyTypeObject` [implementation of `object`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html) and friends does implement.

To change this aspect of the language itself, rather than hacking a replacement of `sys.modules`, you would need to change the C source definitions for `PyModule_Type` and `PyType_Type` such that there were C functions created for `__getitem__` and added to the appropriate location in the C-API big `PyTypeObject` [struct-o-magic-functions](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/newtypes.html#the-basics) (a lot of which is expanded by the macro `PyObject_HEAD`) instead of `0` (which is the sentinel for does not exist), and recompile Python itself with these modified implementations of `module` and `type`.